# Metamask mobile app in iOS Simulator error:s PollingBlockTracker

Tags: javascript, metamask

This question is specific to setting up the open source [metamask-mobile](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile) project.

I am trying to set up the repository locally in order to debug an issue in my dapp. After running `yarn watch` and `yarn start:ios`, the simulator launches. After I open the Metamask app and open the browser, I see a `PollingBlockTracker` error. I have added my infura api key to .js.env file with my infura API key:

```
export MM_INFURA_PROJECT_ID="<my-api-key>
```

Error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Though this will not solve the actual problem, terminating `yarn watch` may at least keep the error from blocking your screen all the time.

If what you are trying to do does not depend on whatever that error is related to, you might still be able to accomplish what you wanted despite the error, then.